# configuration the roots with angular 4

Tags: angular, jakarta-ee, angular-ui-router

i used webStorm 2017.1.4 and i want to construct the front End of my application J2EE. I have 2 components **about** and **contacts** in the last component i want to add all the contacts in the DataBase My Sql but i have a problem **ContactsComponent.ts** when i want to add the type of the Http in the constructor is with bar in the Http but the import library is **import { Http } from '@angular/http';**

here the image
[image]

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
   import { Http } from '@angular/http';
   import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


   @Component({
   selector: 'app-contacts',
   templateUrl: './contacts.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./contacts.component.css']
   })
   export class ContactsComponent implements OnInit {

   pageConstants: any;


   constructor(public http: Http ) {}


   ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/chercherContacts?mc=sa&page=2&size=6')
      .map( resp => resp.json())
      .subscribe( data => {
          this.pageConstants = data;
      }, err => {
        console.log('Erreur : ' + err);
      });
   }
  }
```

i think in this code is correctly but in the console of my google Chrome the erreur is

```
Failed to load http://localhost:8080/chercherContacts?mc=sa&page=2&size=6: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested 
resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4225' is therefore not allowed access.
```

in red and the other mistake is

```
Erreur : Response with status: 0  for URL: null        
contacts.component.ts:25 
zone.js:2969 Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response 
http://localhost:8080/chercherContacts?mc=sa&page=2&size=6 with MIME type 
application/json. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 
for more details.
```

here the image of the mistakesin the google chrome

[image]

can you help me where is the problem in my project with angular 4? 
And thinks of all

Comment: That's because `Http` deprecated, and you should now be using `HttpClient` instead

Comment: i changed Http with HttpClient with the library **import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';** and in **the appModule.ts** the same problem when i imports the **HttpModule** with the library **import {HttpModule} from "@angular/http";**

Comment: Should be `HttpClientModule` from `@angular/common/http`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Http is deprecated in the newer version of angular. It is replaced by Httpclient.

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
constructor(private http: HttpClient){}
```

Rest you can read from here [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http)

Answer (score 0):

the big problem is of the notation in the servlet of the server in the J2EE. it is necessary to add the **@CrossOrigin("*")** this notation is necessary to security to the server external when it is resolve the issue

Already it is occasional to change ** HttpClientModule** of the **appModule.ts** of the library **import { HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';**
And

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/http';
constructor(private http: HttpClient){}
```

and the problem is resolved 
Thank you all my friend :)